# NebulaGraph Database: How to get all the vertices of each tag?

Tags: nebula-graph

I want to get all the vertices of each tag in the Nebula Graph Database.

I tried using `fetch prop on player * yield properties(vertex)` to get the results, but this was not possible.

```
(root@nebula) [basketballplayer]> fetch prop on player * yield properties(vertex)
[ERROR (-1004)]: SyntaxError: syntax error near `* yield '
```

And I tried using neo4j statement `match (v:player) return v`, but it didn't work either.

```
root@nebula) [basketballplayer]> match (v:player) return v
[ERROR (-1005)]: Scan vertices or edges need to specify a limit number, or limit number can not push down.
```

Who can teach me how to use the Nebula Graph database correctly?

Answer (score 0):

By design, the per tag/edge type scan(just like a tabular DBMS data scan) was chosen to be prohibited by default.

Due to the data was stored in NebulaGraph in a more linked/graph way(think of a graph traversal, which started from known nodes and then expand multiple hops along with the edges/relationships). Thus enabling a non-graph scan of data in a distributed graph database like NebulaGraph is costly.

To enable such queries, an index needs to be explicitly created before that [0](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/3.ngql-guide/14.native-index-statements/) or `LIMIT` sample clause [1] was used(could also avoid full scan).

- 
- [1]: example of query(need index for starting node) with LIMIT clause

```
MATCH (v:player) RETURN v LIMIT 100
```

Note: the index is only related to the starting node seeking of the query pattern.